# AS3 Right mouse button drag & drop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent, drag

With Flash Player 11.2, we now have access to mouse events for the right mouse button:

- MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK
- MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN
- MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_UP

However, when I try to use these to implement a right-mouse-button drag&drop, it seems that once the right mouse button is down, I no longer get MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE and the stage's MouseX and MouseY members stop updating until the button is released. This makes it effectively impossible to implement that drag&drop.

Use the code example in Flash Builder below to see what I mean:

- Launch it, move your mouse around and you'll see logs of your mouse position updating.
- Press and hold LMB, move your mouse around, you'll see more logs, great!

  - Release LMB, press and hold LMB, move your mouse around, no logs, bad!

Is this a limitation of AS3? I can't seem to find any documentation about it.

Code Example:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class TestFlash extends Sprite
    {
        public function TestFlash()
        {
            if(stage){
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onLMBDown);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onLMBUp);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN, onRMBDown);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_UP, onRMBUp);
            }

        }

        private function onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            trace("Mouse Pos, from event: x = " + event.localX + " y = " + event.localY + " from stage: x = " + stage.mouseX + " y = " + stage.mouseY);
        }

        private function onRMBDown(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            trace("RMB down");
        }

        private function onRMBUp(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            trace("RMB up");
        }

        private function onLMBDown(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            trace("LMB down");
        }

        private function onLMBUp(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            trace("LMB up");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to produce this result?   I tried in FlashPro just now and it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the problem you are describing, I think you need to add the enter frame function, otherwise the trigger will only activate on the frame that the mouse is clicked and when its released

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dragdrop)
function dragdrop(event:Event):void {
"add dragging event here"
}
```